# Input string was not in a correct format.‎

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I am Passing the Value of the selected in the Gridview for deletion it throws Input String was not in correct format exception My Code is,

```
    protected void gridview1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
   {
    if (e.CommandName.ToUpper().ToString() == "DELETEREC")
    {
        try
        {
            ViewState["id"] = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Trim();
            int r = Namespace.SPs.StoredProcedure(Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["id"])).Execute();//Exception thrown Here
            if (r > 0)
            {
                ClientMessaging("Record Deleted Successfully");
                Clear();
                fillgrid();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            ClientMessaging(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly help me out in this

My SP Method is,

```
    public static StoredProcedure StoredProcedure(int id)
      {
            SubSonic.StoredProcedure sp = new SubSonic.StoredProcedure("StoredProcedure",    DataService.GetInstance("TEST"), "");
           sp.Command.AddParameter("@Id", id, DbType.Int32);

            return sp;
       }
```

Comment: I bet exception  is thrown here `Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["id"])`. Check what is the value of `ViewState["id"]`

Comment: What is the value of `ViewState["id"]` at the time the exception is thrown?

Comment: @ Oleksii & Oded My First Column in the Table is ID and the Second column is MAC address of the System in Varchar format when I convert Viewstate["id"] to string and see it.It is the MAC Addres in the Second Column of the table I want the ID to be passed what can I do???

Comment: post your gridview here where you set the command argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the `e.CommandArgument` is an empty string you get that kind of exception at the     `Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["id"])`

I will try to changing your code in this way

```
    try
    {
        int resultID;
        if(Int32.TryParse(e.CommandArgument.ToString().Trim(), out resultID))
        {
             ViewState["id"] = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Trim();
             .....
        }
        else
            // handle the case of not an integer value
```

**UPDATE** 
Seeing the code of StoredProcedure and with the above code in place then the next reason for the failure is in the StoredProcedure that expects a different type of parameter (For example a NVARCHAR instead of an INT)

Comment: @ Steve My First Column in the Table is ID and the Second column is MAC address of the System in Varchar format when I convert Viewstate["id"] to string and see it.It is the MAC Addres in the Second Column of the table I want the ID to be passed what can I do???

Comment: If the ID is really a number then, probably, the error is inside the call to `Namespace.SPs.StoredProcedure` or the following `Execute` method. Why don't you divide these calls in separate lines. You will be able to see where the error occurs

Comment: @ Steve Can You Please Guide me in Dividing the Calls as I am a Novice in Programming

Comment: On one line put `var objectReturnedByProc = Namespace.SPs.StoredProcedure(Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["ID"]));` and on the second line `objectReturnedByProc.Execute();` In this way you separate the calls and you can say which call fails

Comment: @ Steve The Call is Failing in the ' var objectReturnedByProc = Namespace.SPs.StoredProcedure(Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["ID"])); 'itself

Comment: Then show the code (edit to your current question) of StoredProcedure method

Comment: As it stands now (ID is a real number) there is no reason for the error. Are you sure that the StoredProcedure expects a parameter called @ID of type Int. also put a breakpoint before the conversion and recheck if the ID is really an integer number (And using the code of my answer will no harm your method while giving more robustness to the code)

Comment: @ Steve Thanks for the Response... My Problem is Solved.... the error is only in the Select Command of Stored Procedure....

Comment: Glad for you @Rajesh, I will update the answer to include my last comment so it will be more visible in the future

Answer (score 1):

If you using Command Argument to get the ID you need to set it as command argument in the gridview like `CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>'`

Or else you can use DaTaKey to Get ID field as below

```
<asp:gridview id="gridview1" runat="server" datakeynames="ID"
    ..... >
</asp:gridview>
```

then in Row Command

```
protected void gridview1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.ToUpper().ToString() == "DELETEREC")
    {
        try
        {
            int index = gridview1.SelectedIndex;

            int ID = Convert.ToInt32(gridview1.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString());

            int r = Namespace.SPs.StoredProcedure(ID ).Execute();
            // do stuff 
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            ClientMessaging(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Damith when I used datakeynames in this <Anthem:GridView ID="ggvdetail" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoUpdateAfterCallBack="True" UpdateAfterCallBack="True" Width="100%" OnRowCommand="ggvdetail_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="Id"> it Showed only the Headers of the Grid view While Filling

Comment: @ Damith Thanks for the Response the Error was in my Select command in the Stored Procedure I had Corrected it and it is Working Fine Now...